# How to change registered name, organization and activation key?

Tags: installation, licensing

I have uninstalled mathematica and installed the version provided by my university. However, when I open the software I cannot get rid of the old parameters (license, organization and registered name). How do I make it so mathematica asks me again to insert them?

Comment: Help / Enter Activation Key. Or you can delete `$PasswordFile`, if I got that correctly..

Comment: Why not contact WRI directly?

Comment: Andrea, has my comment helped? That is `DeleteFile @ $PasswordFile`?

Comment: @Kuba yes it was exactly what I wanted. Thanks!